# Visual Studio #include auto-completion shows files everywhere

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way (or any Add-In) to force Visual Studio's `#include` auto-completion to only show valid* paths?

Even better, is there a way to force the auto-complete to follow show only paths relative to the current file or only paths relative to folders in the Additional Include Directories depending on the usage of `#include ""` or `#include <>` respectively?

*By valid paths I mean only paths that would not result in a file-not-found compiler error.

My use case is a project where ALL our files have the same common prefix (cp). Because of this, when I type `#include "cp` it shows me ALL the headers in the entire solution". This makes it not only a little slow sometimes (I can live with that) but also hard to find the header that I want, especially when there are several classes with similar names (or even the same name) across the whole solution.

Comment: Visual Assist seems to help with that. There is a free 7 day trial.